# Exclude backend files from Vite build

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vite

I have built a node backend and recently started to build a frontend using Vue and Vite, stored in the `public` folder. I am using Typescript. I have the following folder structure.

```
build.sh
tsconfig.json
vite.config.ts
├── dist
└── src
    ├── app.js
    ├── backend-app
    ├── backend-frameworks
    └── public
        ├── App.vue
        ├── index.css
        ├── index.html
        ├── main.ts
        ├── components
        └── views
```

and build the `dist` folder with `build.sh`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
rm -r dist || true
tsc -p .
npm run vite-build
```

I have set `tsconfig.json` to ignore the public folder:

```
{
    "extends": "@tsconfig/node16/tsconfig.json",
    "compilerOptions": {
        "outDir": "dist",
        "allowJs": true,
        "jsx": "preserve",
        "lib": ["DOM", "ES2021"]
    },
    "include": ["src/**/*"],
    "exclude": ["node_modules", "src/public"]
}
```

`vite.config.ts`:

```
import { fileURLToPath, URL } from 'url';

import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue';

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [vue()],
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            '@': fileURLToPath(new URL('src/public', import.meta.url)),
        },
    },
    root: 'src/public', // location of index.html relative to project root
    build: {
        outDir: '../../dist/public', // location of build relative to root
    },
});
```

I am aware that `vite` is likely bundling all files in `src`, not just those in `src/public` and although it has been building correctly so far (`tsc` builds a `dist` folder containing the backend files and `vite` builds a `dist/public` folder containing the frontend files), I am now seeing a `vite` build error for a backend file, so I would like to exclude backend files from the `vite build` command - how do I do this?